# Disable mouse and keyboard using python in windows

Tags: python-3.x, block

I am working with python 3.9 and above to develop UI Automation with mouse click and keyboard click.

I need to freeze or block or hold the mouse click, move, drag and keyboard input when my application working in automation.

I've tried

- pynput
- pyHook (only available in 2.7, and I cannot downgrade my python version to 2.7).
- ctypes

none of this method really working in my case.
I am using Windows server as my production environment.

oh, actually i've tried ctypes

```
from ctypes import *

ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(True)
```

but I cannot make it to exe with auto-py-to-exe and other tools to convert py to exe.

Thank you.

Comment: So ctypes does work, but you also need to compile the code into an executable?

Comment: Why do you also need the code to be compiled into an exe? Does your production environment not have python installed?

Comment: @MrChadMWood actually when i run ctypes it doesn't work, so i think i will convert to exe then running it again using administrator..

actually i tried vscode running using administrator then run the python code (ctypes) but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `pywinauto` library to automate UI interactions in Windows. This library allows you to simulate mouse and keyboard inputs, as well as manipulate windows and controls. The library works with Windows GUI, so you can use it to interact with any application that has a GUI.

You can install it using pip:

`pip install pywinauto`

You can then use the `mouse` and `keyboard` modules in `pywinauto` to simulate inputs, for example:

```
from pywinauto.mouse import move, click

# move the mouse to (100, 100)
move(coords=(100, 100))

# left-click at (100, 100)
click(coords=(100, 100))
```

Regarding the conversion of the script to .exe, you could use pyinstaller library to convert your script to .exe format.

`pip install pyinstaller`

Then you can use the command

```
pyinstaller --onefile script_name.py
```

to create the exe version of your script.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this pywinauto to automation my window.. but the thing is, I want to freeze my keyboard and mouse when I'm running my automation..

for example my pywinauto want to click to mouse(300, 200) but then user move the mouse to (400, 500), if that happen, it means i cannot accomplish what i mean to click mouse(300, 200) right..

so i want to block mouse and keyboard while I'm working in my automation.